# Data not showing in English, unless you click on it - In sqldeveloper

Tags: oracle-sql-developer, oracle-xe

I have installed OracleXE and imported data into it.  From SQLPLUS, I can query the data and it all shows up in English.

However, in SQLDEVELOPER, if I look at the data, it's in a nonsense format, unless I double click on it, where it turns into english?  If I query the data through the SQL Worksheet, it displays in rubbish format, but again click on a data item, and it turns into English again?

Before double-clicking:

[image]

After double-clicking:

[image]

I am utterly confused.

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you add a few screenshots (before/after clicking) to show us what's happening?

Comment: Before https://fbcdn-sphotos-h-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-frc1/q71/s720x720/543_10151751994908523_1927041724_n.jpg

Comment: After https://fbcdn-sphotos-c-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-frc1/q71/s720x720/1000851_10151751995008523_523837818_n.jpg

Comment: I believe it is something to do with Java, as I installed some other software, with a java interface, and the same thing seemed to be going on?